# How to disable button after last answer typed in .txt file?

Tags: ios, button

I'm making a word game in xcode! but I need the user to not be able to play after they complete the game... Right know when the complete the game I alert them with a pop up and then take them back to the main menu in ViewController.

But if the user taps on the button at the end of the game they should not be able to play the game any longer. How would I disable the play button at the end of the game?

Code for play button:

```
-(IBAction)btPlayClick:(id)sender{

   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound2);

PlayViewController *viewcontroller = [[PlayViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PlayViewController" bundle:nil];
viewcontroller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

And I have an Int for the current level called "ncurrentLevel"

There are 100 levels and 100 words in the txt file.

How is this done?

Comment: Can you share the code you use when the game is completed?

Comment: @michael not sure that would help michael, the action needs to be implimented in the main view after lvl 100. but if you specify why you'd like to view it, i'll consider it possible.

Answer (score 0):

All **UIControl** classes (which includes *UIButton*) have a property, `enabled`, which determines whether they respond to touch events. You can disable your button by setting its *enabled* property to `NO`. You will most likely need to create and wire up an *IBOutlet* for your button so that you can easily manipulate it.

Of course if the user starts a new game, you will need to re-enable your button :)

Comment: I need to only disable the button after the last level of the game which is level 100 how will I do this man?

Comment: Well it's really not possible to give specifics unless you provide more details about how your app is structured. But you must have some method which processes the user input and increments `ncurrentLevel`. Just have that method disable the button when they have played the 100th level.